# inverse laplace using partial fractions and completing square

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

what is the inverse Laplace transform of this equation $$\frac{1}{(s+1)(s^2+s+1)}$$
I know that completing the square for the quadratic term is required to avoid complex roots and then I need to use partial fractions. After completing the square the denominator becomes:

(s+1)((s+0.5)^2+0.75)

how shall I proceed from here on?

many thanks

Comment: try using convolution theorem

Comment: the convolution is more difficult than the laplace inverse transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

$$\frac{1}{(s+1)(s^2+s+1)} = \frac{A}{s+1}+\frac{Bs+C}{s^2+s+1}$$

Notice that the second term has complex solutions, so it's a good idea if you try to transform it in something like $\frac{s+a}{(s+a)^2+b^2}$ and $\frac{b}{(s+a)^2+b^2}$

The solution is:

$$e^{-t}-\frac{e^{-t/2} (\sqrt3 \cos(\frac{\sqrt3 t}{2})-\sin(\frac{\sqrt3 t}{2}))}{\sqrt3}$$

---

$1)\frac{s+a}{(s+a)^2+b^2} \to e^{-a}\cos(bt)$
$2)\frac{b}{(s+a)^2+b^2} \to e^{-a}\sin(bt)$

Example:
If $B=1$ and $C=1$

$$\frac{s+1}{s^2+s+1} = \frac{s+1}{(s+\frac12)^2+(1-\frac14)} = $$

$$\frac{s}{(s+\frac12)^2+(\frac34)} + \frac{\sqrt{\frac34}}{(s+\frac12)^2+(\frac34)}*(\sqrt{\frac43})    $$

In this case you have to add $\sqrt{\frac43}$, so the numerator can be equal to $1$, but you need $\sqrt{\frac34}$ to use the  second transform (obviously you will add $\sqrt{\frac43}$ to the result of this transformation).

...

In your case is $A=1, B=-1, C=0$, so:

$$\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{s}{(s+\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$

Now, to use the transformation $1)$ you need something to add to the fraction like that:
$$\frac{{\frac12}}{(s+\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$

So:

$$\frac{1}{s+1}-(\frac{s}{(s+\frac12)^2+\frac34} + \frac{{\frac12}}{(s+\frac12)^2+\frac34} - \frac{{\frac12}}{(s+\frac12)^2+\frac34}) $$

So:

$$\frac{1}{s+1}-(\frac{s+{\frac12} }{(s+\frac12)^2+\frac34}  - \frac{{\frac12}}{(s+\frac12)^2+\frac34}) $$

That becomes:

$$\frac{1}{s+1}-(\frac{s+{\frac12} }{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac34}  - \frac{{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}{(s+\frac12)^2+\frac34}*\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}*\frac12 )$$

Comment: can you please explain more on the transformation you mentioned in the end?

Comment: @user84310 Sure

Comment: thank you, but I think in my case A=1, B=7/3 and C=0, so can you please modify your answer to fit these values?

Comment: @user84310 Ok, now I think that you can continue easily  ;)

Comment: Billions of thanks :)